# Large file uploads

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm working on an application that allows the upload, and storage of large files on a web server.  Currently I'm using PHP to handle POSTed files via http.  I have my php.ini set with:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
memory_limit = 128M
max_input_time = 6000
max_execution_time = 6000
```

There doesn't seem to be any apache directive set for LimitRequestBody.  I use APC to track file upload progress.  For some reason the file upload always halts at 50M exactly.

I know http isn't the most efficient solution for file uploads, but this app needs to be user friendly, and I understand there are firewall issues with ftp.

I'm wondering if anyone could give me some suggestions as to what is halting my download at exactly 50M?  It must be some sort of configuration setting.

Additionally, is there some other way I should consider working around using javascript / PHP and http for file uploads.  I've looked into java applets and using flash.  Possibly going to use swfuploader, but if its a server config that's causing my upload to fail via http, I don't really see how a java applet or flash uploader would get around that.

I should note that I'm hoping to come up with a solution that will allow me to upload very large files up to 1 GB at some point.

I use very simplistic PHP to receive the file

```
$uploaddir = '/'.$_POST['upload_directory'].'/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {  some success code; }
```

There's obviously a little more to it than that, but that's the gist of how I handle the upload.

Comment: How are you uploading the files, and what are you doing with them after you upload them?

Comment: simple php is_uploaded_file() and move_uploaded_file() commands and pulling the files out of  $_FILES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours of banging my head I've solved the problem.  I am using Extjs for front end components.  The upload widget I'm using had a hard-coded setting in it that sets the MAX_ UPLOAD _FILESIZE property of the POST request to 50M, over-writing the value I set it to elsewhere.  It's now working as expected.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Set the LimitRequestBody directive in your vhost.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-limiting-upload-size/

Comment: this article is about how to set LimitRequestBody to limit your upload size.  If I don't have LimitRequestBody set, then is it not already unlimited?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody says "If the client request exceeds that limit, the server will return an error response instead of servicing the request". If you don't get an error response in the browser this isn't the problem...

Comment: ya, I don't get an error, so I know this isn't the problem.  I don't have enough 'reputation' to downvote the answer, but this answer doesn't help at all