# exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException' Uploading large files laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel-4, upload

In a view in laravel i have a form that upload a file:

```
<form id="file-submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="store">
            {{ Form::token() }}
            <input id="filename" name="filename" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload file" id="file-save" class="btn btn-create" />
        </form>
```

In the route file i have:

```
Route::post('/store', 'MyController@upload');
```

There in the method, i process the file data.

This works in my local server, i upload it in production, so, this works when i upload files around 5kb, but if i try to upload a large file, around 4MB it breaks with this error:

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException' in <laravel_instance>/protected/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:210
```

I have the same memory settings in php.ini file (memory_limit, post_max_size, excecution_time, max_input_time, upload_max_size)

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343193/large-file-uploads?rq=1 ... There are some other links in the "Related" box to the right of this question, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it has something to do with you manually creating the form.

Try doing it like this:

Route:

```
Route::post('/store', [
    'as' => 'store',
    'uses' => 'MyController@upload'
]);
```

Form:

```
{{Form::open([
    'id' => 'file-submit',
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    'action' => 'store'
])}}

{{Form::file('filename')}}

{{Form::submit()}}

{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: Hi Budhajeewa, i'm sorry for late response.
I Make the changes that you suggest, the result is the same (with better code), so, i see the file is already uploaded.
The file is a csv file, with that i make registry to the database, so, in the middle of the proccess is when the app crash.